# How to remove drop shadow from QToolTip

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qtooltip

I want to modify the style of all the tool tip windows in my application.

As an example, this QSS : (you can try it in the QtDesigner application)

```
QToolTip
{
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: red;
}
```

Give this result :

[image]

My problem is to remove the drop shadow effect, and more specifically the white corner here :

[image]

I know this can be done by changing the windows flags, but is there any way to change this **globally**, I mean to set the correct flags somewhere and then all the application use this for displaying tool tip ?

Changing the flags would need to filter all "ToolTip" events on all widgets to provide a custom QToolTip class. This is a lot of work for a big application (about 50 *.ui forms).

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the `background-clip` property:

```
QToolTip
{
    background-clip: border;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: red;
}
```

Also a `QToolTip` holds a `QLabel` to display the actual text.  You could try targeting that explicitly with `QToolTip QLabel { border: ...; }` and make the actual `QToolTip` background transparent.

Comment: Thanks, but I still have blanck corners. I think his is added by the OS windows management system, since the drop shadow effect is part of Windows, not Qt (AFAIK)